# Should "What decent web frameworks exists for functional programming" be a wiki answer?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, curated-answers

[What decent web-frameworks exists for functional programming?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3049/what-decent-web-frameworks-exists-for-functional-programming#question) is a potentially good topic to have a curated list <sup>*</sup>. Yea or Nay?

<sub><sup>*</sup> See: [New lock type for truly collaborative questions and answers](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5991/new-lock-type-for-truly-collaborative-questions-and-answers)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

I'm thinking no.

Unlike [the prime example for collaborative answers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-should-every-programmer-know-about-web-development), this would tend to focus on particular products. Products tend to change a lot more frequently than topics. Products reach end-of-life and new products are created more often than paradigm shifts, meaning it will take more effort to curate. I'm concerned that there wouldn't be enough curation, especially over a long period of time. if the answer falls out of date, its usefulness would drop.

Something else to consider is that library recommendations are off-topic. I'm not sure how a curated list of web frameworks differ from a question asking about what library to use. It's a blurry enough line with the "things to know for web development" question, since questions about what to learn next are off-topic. Perhaps there's enough of a distinction between what tools exist and what tool should I use, but it is worth thinking about.

Comment: your insight looks worth integrating into [New lock type...](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/5991) guidance, particularly the point of not ab/using new lock type to cover [list questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/list-questions/info "what's this")

Comment: @gnat Added an answer there. If you have any other ideas, comment or edit my answer, I suppose.